# How can I determine the source and/or contents of a .swp file?

Tags: macos

I have a `>36 GB` file at `$HOME/.swp` on macOS. The file is over 2 years old, I'd like that space back, but I'm super curious as to what it could be.

How can I figure out what app/process/program made it and whether it's trying to help me like save some state I've since thought lost?